# What is the alternative to list add method

Tags: java, list

I got a strange question from my friend. Is there any other alternative to adding an object to a `List` without using the `add` method?

Comment: You could potentially use `addAll()`, but why would you want to?

Comment: A question from your friend? Or homework assignment?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative? Do you need to do something besides just add the object to the list? Weird question

Comment: people are here to help the programmer who make some research on there task please provide some of you research which you had did.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this isn't considered "cheating", but there are a couple of ways to add items without calling `add(Object)` yourself:

First, you could use `addAll(Collection<T>)`. Since this method receives a `Collection`, you could wrap your object with `Collections.singleton(T)`:

```
myList.addAll(Collections.singleton(myObject));
```

A similar solution would be to wrap your object with such a `Collection` and create your `List` using it:

```
List<SomeClass> myList = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(myObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(otherList);
list.addAll(otherList); // Collection<String>
Collections.addAll(list, "unu", "du", "tri"); // Variable args
list.add("kvar");
list.add(4, "kvin"); // Insert at index
```